# Objective C - Unit Testing & Mocking Objects?

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, dependency-injection, mocking

How do you unit test Objective C code? (iPhone)

In other languages such as java and .Net you can use Dependency Injection, to be able to unit test and pass mocked object in your current code.
However, I could not find a reliable dependency injection framework for objective c.

Let's say you want to write a unit test for the code below, how can you mock MyObject?

```
- (void) methodToBeTested
{
     NSString str = @"myString";
     MyObject object = [[MyObject alloc] init];
     [object setString:str];
     [object doStuff];
     [object release];
}
```

This is how I would do it with dependency injection. Is there a similar way to achieve this on objective c?

```
@Inject MyObject object;

public void methodToBeTested()
{
     String str = "myString";
     // object is automatically instantiated (Dependency Injection)
     object.setString(str);
     object.doStuff();
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Inversion of control is still feasible in objective-c. You can certainly design your classes with constructor-based or property-based dependency injection in mind but I don't think you'll find an annotation based dependency injection framework like you are used to.

```
[[ClassToBeTested alloc] initWithDependency:foo andOtherDepedency:bar];

ClassToBeTested *objectUnderTest = [[ClassToBeTested alloc] init];
objectUnderTest.dependency = foo;
objectUnderTest.otherDependency = bar;
```

I've seen a couple of different approaches to building dependency injection frameworks for objective-c including https://github.com/mivasi/Objective-IOC but I can't comment on their maturity or usefulness.

For object mocking and stubbing look at [OCMock](http://www.mulle-kybernetik.com/software/OCMock/).

Comment: Another fantastic mocking lib, especially with regards to ease of use is: https://github.com/jonreid/OCMockito

Answer (score 7):

> how can you mock MyObject?

```
- (void) methodToBeTestedWithObject:(MyObject *)object
{
     NSString str = @"myString";
     [object setString:str];
     [object doStuff];
}
```

To test:

```
- (void)testMethodToBeTested {
    id mockMyObject = [OCMock mockForClass:[MyObject class]];

    [[mockMyObject expect] setString:[OCMock any]];
    [[mockMyObject expect] doStuff];

    [objectToTest methodToBeTestedWithObject:mockMyObject];
    [mockMyObject verify];
}
```

Using, as mentioned in @Jonah's answer, the excellent [OCMock](http://www.mulle-kybernetik.com/software/OCMock/). Don't bother trying to do capital-D, capital-I Dependency Injection in obj-c, it's more work than it's worth.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a dependency injection framework for Objective-C: http://www.typhoonframework.org

Besides addressing on the design aspects of DI, it has a strong focus on being able to configure components for production vs test scenarios (integration testing). This includes:

- Ability to inject values represented as strings - these are converted to the required type at runtime.
- Configuration management via an external properties file.
- Asynchronous test execution - allowing you to test methods that run on a background thread.

Comment: Very flexible and full of features, but too complicated to use. I ended up writing my own DI framework, which uses dynamic properties to lazy initialize dependencies based on a pre-set binding. https://github.com/aryaxt/OCInjection

Comment: There are quite a few DI libs for obj-c using the approach you chose. Eg Objection and AppleGuice. guice-style is nice, but I wanted something that, for example, makes it easy to have two components backed by the same protocol. . . I think it compares well in ease of use. . What part did you struggle with? Am planning to improve docs. . congrats on your nice lib :)

Comment: Definitely not a big fan of objection, I hate the idea of having to define the dependencies using a string and a macro. AppleGuice seems really interesting very simple. My lib is very limited, it only supports property injection and 1 to 1 binding form 1 interface to 1 implementation. Typhonn is very powerful and flexible like I said before. I guess I'm not a big fan of having to define initializer for each dependency, or in the other words I'm a lazy developer. I want everything to be automated :) Great work though very cool features.

Comment: I think it would be helpful to create the sample project as simple as possible, and only demonstrate the use of DI.

Comment: @aryaxt - thanks for the feedback. . I'll try to make the docs clearer and sample app simpler. . . 1) You only need to specify an initializer if you want DI via an initializer. . 2) You can do simple property injection by placing eg: autoWire(@selector(quest), @selector(horse)) in your class. . . If you rename the property in the IDE these get renamed too . . (Auto-wiring in the docs). . . Thanks again for feedback and congrats on your lib.